# React Native -> navigation.navigate("Dashboard");

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

export default function Login({navigation}) {
using business logic
navigation.navigate("Dashboard");
}
then so error
React Native ->  The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Dashboard"} was not handled by any navigator.  Do you have a screen named 'Dashboard'?  If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nes

how can resolve of this type of problem

Comment: Please provide us with the code of the navigators.